# Merge & Filter Multiple Columns of One Dataframe with Boolean Logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, boolean

Objective: Output buy/sell/neutral/error indicators to a single df[column] while filtering out "False" values. Indicators are based on the below dataframe column, and then formulated with a boolean statement:

```
df['sma_10'] = pd.DataFrame(ta.SMA(df['close'], timeperiod=10), dtype=np.float, columns=['close'])      
df['buy'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] > df['sma_10'], columns=['buy'])   
df['buy'] = df['buy'].replace({True: 'BUY'})        
df['sell'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] < df['sma_10'], columns=['sell'])     
df['sell'] = df['sell'].replace({True: 'SELL'})         
df['neutral'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] == df['sma_10'], columns=['neutral'])       
df['neutral'] = df['neutral'].replace({True: 'NEUTRAL'})        
df['error'] = pd.DataFrame((df['buy'] == False) & (df['sell'] == False) & (df['neutral'] == False), columns=['Error'])      
df['error'] = df['error'].replace({True: 'ERROR'})
```

Current output of df

```
buy  sell  Neutral Error
False False False ERROR
BUY False False False
False SELL False False
False False NEUTRAL False
```

Desired output of df

```
Indicator
ERROR
BUY
SELL
NEUTRAL
```

Attempts & Methods:
1st Method: Merging all the buy/sell/neutral/error columns and attempting to drop "False" values. Dataframe only iterates once before erroring out.

```
df['sma_10_indic']=[df['buy'].astype(str)+df['sell'].astype(str)+df['neutral'].astype(str)+df['error'].astype(str)].drop("False")
```

I have tried a subroutine of if & elif's such as:
This method also errors out before the first index

```
df['buy'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] > df['sma_10'])
df['sell'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] < df['sma_10'])
df['neutral'] = pd.DataFrame(df['close'] == df['sma_10'])
error = ((buy == False) and (sell == False) and (neutral == False))
if (df['buy'] == "True"):
   df['sma_10_indic'] = pd.DataFrame("BUY",columns=['indicator'])
elif (df['sell'] == "True"):
   df['sma_10_indic'] = pd.DataFrame("SELL",columns=['indicator'])
elif (df['neutral'] == "True"):
   df['sma_10_indic'] = pd.DataFrame("NEUTRAL",columns=['indicator'])
elif (error == True):
   df['sma_10_indic'] = pd.DataFrame("ERROR",columns=['indicator'])
```

I am unsure on the path ahead, I have been beating my head against the wall for about 14 hours on this one with no clear path ahead. I have also tried creating another seperate dataframe and merging them via concat with no luck due to the boolean. I am relatively new to python and pandas/dataframes, so please be patient with me. Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['close'] > df['sma_10']
m2 = df['close'] < df['sma_10']
m3 = df['close'] == df['sma_10']

df['Indicator'] = np.select([m1, m2, m3], ['BUY','SELL','NEUTRAL'], 'ERROR')
```

Comment: Wow. That not only cleared up the coding block I had but it also made the routine even faster. Thank you very much!